# Find the equation of the curve for which the area bounded by the tangent, the normal, and the y-axis is proportional to the slope.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I'm learning diff equations from the Elementary Differential Equations by Kells, Third Edition, and I have this problem that I'm not very sure how to think about. what I've done so far leads to nothing.
I tried thinking the problem as a rectangular triangle and doing the most simple think I could think of,
$A=\frac{1}{2}bh$,
replacing 
$b=T=y'x+b$ 
and 
$h=N=-\frac{1}{y'}x+a$
 where T and N stand for normal and tangent line.
The idea was then to do
$y'=kA$
and solve the differential equation. But when I tried this, I could not reach a solution due to the fact that one of the y' is left in the denominator.
I see no way of doing this, since I have also considered dividing variables but I do not see how this would be done.
In the textbook, the solution is said to be
$x^2+(y-c)^2=2k$.

Comment: Think carefully about what exactly the base and height of the triangle is, given a generic point $(x, y)$ and the slope of the tangent $y'$ at that point. You should end up with a very easy-to-solve differential equation, so if it's hard, that means you're making some mistake in the first step

Comment: Seems to be that I'm making that first step mistake. I'm gonna think about it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let a point on the curve have coordinates $(X,Y)$ with gradient $Y’$.

The equation of the tangent at that point is $$y-Y=Y’(x-X)$$
This intersects the $y$ axis when $x=0\implies y=Y-XY’$

The equation of the normal is $$y-Y=-\frac{1}{Y’}(x-X)$$
This intersects the $y$ axis where $y=Y+\frac{X}{Y’}$

The base of the triangle has length equal to the difference between these $y$ values, which is $$\left|XY’+\frac{X}{Y’}\right|$$

Assuming $X,Y>0$ and $Y’>0$, the area of the triangle is $$\frac12\left(X^2Y’+\frac{X^2}{Y’}\right)$$

Now the differential equation is $$\frac12\left(X^2Y’+\frac{X^2}{Y’}\right)=kY’$$

Now rearrange this and get $$Y’=\pm\frac{X}{\sqrt{2k-X^2}}$$

Integrating gives $$Y=\mp\sqrt{2k-X^2}+c$$

And hence the expected answer.

Comment: s**t I forgot that you could write the tangent line like that haha. Thanks a lot for the help!